# ext.net mvc show combobox with default selected value 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ext.net

i'm using `EXT.NET` ComboBoxFor control and binding it with the items collection.
below is my html

```
 X.ComboBoxFor(c => c.COUNTRY_CD).FieldLabel("Select Country").ID("CmbCountry").Editable(false).Width(300).Items(from p in Model.CountryList select new Ext.Net.ListItem { Text = p.COUNTRY_DESC, Value = p.COUNTRY_CD.ToString() })
```

how can i set the combobox to show the default value selected to be 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution

```
X.ComboBoxFor(c => c.CountryList[0].COUNTRY_CD).FieldLabel("Select Country").ID("CmbCountry").Editable(false).Width(300).Items(from p in Model.CountryList select new Ext.Net.ListItem { Text = p.COUNTRY_DESC, Value = p.COUNTRY_CD.ToString() })
```

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
<Combobox>.Select(0);
```

or use the property `SelectedItem`

Comment: `X.ComboBoxFor(c => c.COUNTRY_CD).FieldLabel("Select Country").ID("CmbCountry").Editable(false).Width(300).Items(from p in Model.CountryList select new Ext.Net.ListItem { Text = p.COUNTRY_DESC, Value = p.COUNTRY_CD.ToString() }).SelectedItem(0)` does this work?